# OpenCV ptr in Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I was wondering how to make this opencv c++ code in Java

```
uchar *ptr = eye.ptr<uchar>(y);
```

I have been looking around and I think I can use the uchar as a byte... but I have no idea what the code to get the .ptr in java

Heres my code so far

```
private Rect getEyeball(Mat eye, MatOfRect circles) {
    int[] sums = new int[circles.toArray().length];

    for (int y = 0; y < eye.rows(); y++) {
        // OpenCV method uchar *ptr = eye.ptr<uchar>(y); Goes here 
    }

    int smallestSum = 9999999;
    int smallestSumIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.toArray().length; i++) {
        if (sums[i] < smallestSum) {
            smallestSum = sums[i];
            smallestSumIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return circles.toArray()[smallestSumIndex];
}
```

The full C++ code is

```
cv::Vec3f getEyeball(cv::Mat &eye, std::vector<cv::Vec3f> &circles)
{
    std::vector<int> sums(circles.size(), 0);
    for (int y = 0; y < eye.rows; y++)
    {
        uchar *ptr = eye.ptr<uchar>(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < eye.cols; x++)
        {
            int value = static_cast<int>(*ptr);
            for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
            {
                cv::Point center((int)std::round(circles[i][0]), (int)std::round(circles[i][1]));
                int radius = (int)std::round(circles[i][2]);
                if (std::pow(x - center.x, 2) + std::pow(y - center.y, 2) < std::pow(radius, 2))
                {
                    sums[i] += value;
                }
            }
        ++ptr;
        }
    }
    int smallestSum = 9999999;
    int smallestSumIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sums[i] < smallestSum)
        {
            smallestSum = sums[i];
            smallestSumIndex = i;
         }
    }
    return circles[smallestSumIndex];
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do once you get the `ptr`? Sum along the row?

Comment: (Note that you don't actually need the `sums` array if that's the case)

Comment: (And that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a more robust initial value of `smallestSum`; although it is better again to use the sum for `i == 0`, just in case all rows sum to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: Yeah, I have added the C++ code

Comment: ( formatting was a pain in the butt )

Comment: BTW: assuming your circles are smaller than the image, your code could be a lot more efficient if you moved the circle loop from being the innermost to the outermost, and then make your loops over y and x only loop over the bounding box of that circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distilling down your C++:

```
for (int y = 0; y < eye.rows; y++)
{
    uchar *ptr = eye.ptr<uchar>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < eye.cols; x++)
    {
      int value = static_cast<int>(*ptr);
      // A loop not using ptr.
      ++ptr;
    }
}
```

You're simply getting the pixel value at (x,y) from `eye`.

So, just use one of the overloads of [`Mat.get`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get-int-int-).

```
int[] values = new int[eye.channels()];
for (int y = 0; y < eye.rows(); y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < eye.cols(); x++) {
    eye.get(x, y, values);
    int value = values[0];

    // A loop not using ptr.
  }
}
```

Note that using `get(int, int, int[])` rather than `get(int, int)` here means that you avoid allocating a new array for each iteration, which will make things a heck of a lot faster.

Comment: Hello Andy, I am trying to read opencv_core.Mat values in java as well. I have rows(), cols() method in it, but any version of .get() method seems to be missing at my end.

I am new to it, can you please help me know what I should do?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443053/reading-values-in-opencv-face-lbphfacerecognizer-gethistograms